# tree.xpath() returns empty list in Webscraping using lxml library

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, youtube, lxml

When you go to :
https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending

3 buttons : music gaming movies appears

i wanted to select the music element's `<a>` tag . so i could extract the href value from it. i used the below code but it keeps giving me an empty list.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml import etree

url =  "https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending"

response = urlopen(url)
htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(response, htmlparser)
print(tree.xpath('//*[@id="contents"]/ytd-channel-list-sub-menu-avatar-renderer[1]/a'))
```

Comment: I don't expect those buttons will be there in the first HTML payload. You have to run the javascript as well so the buttons will be loaded. Use the developer console (Network tab) to find out what you get from a single url. Based on my quick inspection my assumption seems right.

Comment: @rene so dude , youre saying that these elements that i want to   select are created by js and i got empty list beacause it hadnt been loaded yet?. is there a topic/function  i can research for completely loading   the site with its js . ive been searching this for a while but all i get are for selenium.

Comment: Well dude, I have no idea, I'm not a python dev, nor familiar with Beatifulsoup. Selenium utilizes a real browser so that is why you see that a lot. I'm not aware of any out of the box options that don't use an installed webbrowser to do the heavy lifting of loading resources, executing its javascript and offering you a DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use selenium if requests is not working. I have tried it at my end using selenium and it is working flawlessly. Below is the code which you can refer.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import *
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


URL = "https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending"

chrome_options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver/chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)#download chrome driver and add path here.
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get(URL)

wait1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 200)
wait1.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="img"]')))
print('-' * 100)
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contents"]/ytd-channel-list-sub-menu-avatar-renderer[1]/a').get_attribute('href'))
print('-' * 100)
```

[image: URL fetched from anchor tag]